# No module named 'Crypto' Error facing on Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pycrypto

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.7 and facing this error from [Crypto.Cipher import AES "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'"]

Already installed this successfully:
C:\Users\Zeeeshan Abbas>pip install pycryptodomex
Collecting pycryptodomex
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/ec/1cd58f9e16980db055b5ab501e8833456ca0af1e3fef190e73a0c8674cc4/pycryptodomex-3.8.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (10.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.0MB 384kB/s
Installing collected packages: pycryptodomex
Successfully installed pycryptodomex-3.8.2

But still facing the error:
D:\Coursera\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Coursera/Python/ctr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Coursera/Python/ctr.py", line 11, in 
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Comment: make sure you have activated and are in your virtual environment when running the pip command otherwise you're installing your requirements somewhere else.

Comment: I need to set the path where I have installed python? or where I am saving the current python file?

Comment: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2   this is where I have installed python. But am working in D-drive

Comment: I have 'Cryptodome' in my site-packages as well

Comment: D:\Coursera\Python\venv\   "venv" stands for virtual environment, so this is where you need to install pycryptodomex .  Make sure you activate the virtual environment  D:\Coursera\Python\venv\Scripts\activate.  Then run the pip install pycryptodomex

Comment: Thank you very much!! I installed it here: D:\Coursera\Python\venv\Scripts and it worked...

Comment: I'll make the comment the official answer and you can accept so others know how to resolve as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D:\Coursera\Python\venv\ "venv" stands for virtual environment, so this is where you need to install pycryptodomex . Make sure you activate the virtual environment D:\Coursera\Python\venv\Scripts\activate. Then run the pip install pycryptodomex

Comment: I have changed this "from Crypto.Cipher import AES" to "from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES".